# what happens when transistors are interchanged in CMOS?

Tags: transistors, cmos, nmos, pmos

A basic cmos inverter will have a P-transistor upside and N-transistor down side. what happens if we reverse the p and n transistors?

Comment: They become CMON transistors (Complimentary Metal Oxide Neverconductor).

Answer (score 7):

Nothing will happen. Neither transistor will be able to turn on.

The N-channel enhancement-mode transistor requires its gate to be at a higher voltage than the source (or drain), which can't happen if it's connected to Vcc.

Similarly, the P-channel transistor requires a negative voltage on its gate, which can't happen if it's connected to ground.

Comment: If you want to thank me, upvote the answer and accept it. (Although, to be honest, we generally encourage waiting at least 24 hours to accept, in case a better answer comes along.)

Comment: Nope, they should still be able to turn on.  But the issue is very visible in the two other answers.   The buffer won't be able to have rail-to-rail output levels due to the threshold voltage.

Answer (score 4):

Unloaded outputs:0.18u process using Thick Oxide (0.35u transistors)
Input is a 1us slow ramp and decay to show transitions, other line is the output of the inverter and green line is the strange case with PMOS and NMOS flipped with bulk connection as per normal.

[image: simulation]

Comment: You need to add an explanation of what these graphs represent. I can guess, but I shouldn't have to.

Comment: @DaveTweed context is an input, inverter output and the flipped NMOS and PMOS as per the original question.

Comment: Is there any load on the output, or is it just floating? How much current is actually flowing in the transistors? What simulator did you use?

Comment: @DaveTweed  What you are seeing is sub-threshold behaviour emphasized by DIBL, GIDL and the back gate effect.  The assymetry is due to the fact that the transistors are sized differently PMOS 2X) for active mode operation, in sub-threshold they tend to be better balanced in W/L.  Simulator is a production simulator using foundry decks.  The flipped version falls under the classification of a trans-linear circuit, it would be acceptable to use in low voltage situations.  I'll run other sims later and add a 0.65 rail version. It will be interesting.

Comment: I will not be adding like I said above, as it takes it too far away from the original intent of the question.

Comment: Might it be helpful to, for both inverters, plot the output behavior when driving a 1mA current source and a 1mA current sink, to help show that the green trace appears to lags behind the input not because it's delayed in time, but rather because the output will want to stay where it is unless the input voltage is about a volt higher or lower.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: CMOS nonverter]

At first glance, this looks like it could be a CMOS buffer: T1 = T2. You'd think that the channel would be opened or closed by the voltage difference between the body and the gate, regardless of what the drain and the source are doing.

I built this thing with a [CD4007UB](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=CD4007UBNSRG4virtualkey59500000virtualkey595-CD4007UBNSRG4). You do get an output signal in phase. But it's err...weird. My scope is analog, so I don't have a good way to give you a picture, but Vcc was 5V, and I gave it a 5V p-p 1kHz square wave input. The output was a square wave in phase, with sharp rises but very slow falls. The low output was at 0V, but the high was only about 2.5V.

I'm an amateur electrical engineer, not a physicist, so I can't explain all this behavior, but from other's comments and what I've learned from my own research, I have a pretty good guess of what's happening here. Check out this diagram of MOSFET operation from [Wikipedia's page on MOSFETs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET):

[image: MOSFET operation]

If you see in the bottom two images, the conductive channel in the middle doesn't go all the way across. However, some charge carriers (electrons or holes for N and P channel MOSFETS, respectively) are still able to sneak across by some physical reason I don't fully understand. The reason it's pinched off here is that the width of the conducting layer is a function of the voltage difference between the gate and what's near it, and for most of the gate, that's the body. But near the pinched off end, the gate is near the drain. Unless you can get the gate \$V{th}\$ above the drain, you can't open the channel all the way across.

Ordinarily, once you get it close, then some current can flow. Once that starts to happen, the voltage across the load connected to the drain increases, and consequently, the voltage at the drain must decrease. This opens the channel a bit more, more current flows, and so on, until the drain voltage is at its minimum, the channel is as wide as it can get, and the transistor is fully on.

Problem is, in this circuit, the gate can't get significantly higher than the drain *or* the source. So even though there's a conductive channel in the middle, it's pinched off at *both* ends, and what you are left with are two P-N diodes in opposite directions. No current can flow.

That's my guess. I suspect asymmetries in the manufacturing of N and P channel devices, and the less than perfect calibration of my test equipment explain why it sort of works a little, asymmetrically.

Comment: You have a point: The conductive channel in an N-channel MOSFET is formed when the gate-substrate bias modifies the distribution of electrons in the depletion region that forms under the gate to the point where some of them are in the conduction band. However, this is where I'm out of my depth on the physics. It can't work the way you're thinking, or else CMOS transmission gates wouldn't need both N-channel and P-channel devices; just an N-channel device would be enough. But I don't know what the reason is.

Comment: @DaveTweed I think you do need P and N channel devices, even so. How else would you make a CMOS totem-pole? You could do RTL with just N-channel MOSFETs, but what would be the point of that?

Comment: OK, I looked it up in my college textbook. When the gate and drain/source are at the same potential, the channel is "pinched off" at that end. In normal operation, with the source connected to the substrate, this pinchoff occurs only at the drain end, and the drain voltage at which this occurs marks the transition from linear mode to saturated mode. But if the source is also at the gate voltage, the channel is pinched off at *both* ends, and no current can flow, even if there's an inverted channel near the center of the gate.

Comment: @DaveTweed I'm having a hard time getting my head around that without a picture, but I'll get a good empirical answer to the question when I build it tonight.

Comment: @DaveTweed built! You are right...it doesn't really behave predictably. But it does do _something_.

Comment: I hope that when you built this that you used two separate packages to individually get access to a NMOS and PMOS, but even then the circuit won't be the same.  You have to look at the bulks carefully.

Comment: @rawbrawb no, just one 4007, which has three CMOS inverters but with a separate connection to the bulks. I figured that would be similar to how it would be fabricated, if one were to do such a thing. Is that wrong?

Comment: THe name Pinch Off voltage originates from the old days when when only strong inversion was known and the inversion layer was assumed to be "pinched off" (it's charge assumed to decrease to zero)  In fact nothing is pinched off the inversion charge is significant.  You see a slope in the channel shape to be able to support the fact that there is a lateral e-feild from S -> D.

Comment: It could be, I don't know the process details to be able to be sure.

Comment: @rawbrawb well, let's just say both my experiment and your simulation agree the circuit doesn't do much of anything useful, and leave it at that :)

Comment: comment on pinch off comes from "operation and modelling of the CMOS transistor" by Yannis Tsividis

Comment: I disagree, just because it doesn't work as an inverter any more doesn't mean it's useless.  It just means it is no longer an inverter.  These class of circuits are used in various parts of IC design, the use of the back gate enables unusual operation and functionality.